# How do I set the font in command line vim (vim for windows)?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, vimrc

everything I see says I should use guifont but if I open a console and try to tab complete set gui--- I only see `set guicursor`

Im using command line vim not gui vim.

What do I put in vimrc to set font and size?

Comment: You need to set the font in the Windows Console.

Comment: is that possible with a powershell command?

Comment: [Customizing powershell font face and size](//serverfault.com/a/548125)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font:

Console Vim uses whatever font the console/terminal is using. Changing the font in your terminal is done differently depending on your system and the terminal in use. Consult the documentation or manpages for your terminal, or do a web search for how to change the font in your chosen terminal. Vim cannot use a different font than the rest of the terminal.

When running inside a terminal, Vim can, at most, change the colours (within the limits of the colours supported by the terminal: sometimes bold and unbold black and white, often 8 colours plus bold/unbold foreground only [or seen another way, 8 background and 16 foreground]; on X11 some terminals support up to 256 background and foreground colours; "changing colours" usually also includes the use of reverse-video), and, if the terminal supports them (not all terminals do, and even those which do may support it only with certain fonts), use bold, underline and/or italic.

Source: [Increase font size in Vim editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363142/increase-font-size-in-vim-editor)

We can refer to the way in  **Increase font size in Vim editor** .